# Как вывести данные из таблицы при использовании префикса в БД Laravel

Tags: laravel

В настройках mysql указан префикс

```
'mysql' => [
  'prefix' => 'm1_',
]
```

Также в это БД хранятся таблицы без префикса, потребовалось вывести данные из таблицы, у которой не указан префикс.

Получилось вывести через `сырой sql-запрос`

```
DB::select('select * from categories')
```

Так же пробовал вывести таким образом

```
DB::table('categories')->get()
```

Но он ничего не выводит
Получается при использовании `table` он подставляет префикс?
И как можно использовать 2 вариант, только в настройках указывать второе соединение уже без префикса, создавать модель и в ней указывать второе соединение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в конфиге еще одно соединение с настройками без префикса:

```
'mysql_without_prefix' => [
  'prefix' => '',
]
```

И у модели, которая связана с таблицей `categories` укажите это соединение:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_without_prefix';
```

Если предположить, что модель, которая связана с таблицей `categories` называется `Category`, то данные нужно будет получать так:

```
Category::get()
```